# How to compare columns in two dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem where I want to check if first two columns of two dataframes are identical or not ?
Let say I have `dataframe1` with columns `["Date","Day","Volume"]` and another `dataframe2` with columns `["Date","Day"]`. I want to check if these two data frames are having Date and Day in the same structure or not? How can I achieve this in the most optimized way?

Answer (score 3):

If want compare exactly same values, same index and same length between 2 columns use [`DataFrame.equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) with subset of columns by list:

```
mask = df1[['Date','Day']].equals(df2[['Date','Day']])
```

If second df2 has only  2 columns:

```
mask = df1[['Date','Day']].equals(df2)
```